# Ошибка A component named "Primary Key" already exists (Borland C++)

Tags: borland, c++

Здравствуйте!

Пишу в Borland C++ программу, которая обращается к БД. При компиляции вылетает

> A component named "Primary Key" already exists.

Программа работает, но при попытке внести изменения в БД ругается:

> исключение class EOleExsception with message: "Невозможно добавление или изменение записи. Для обеспечения целостности данных необходимо наличие связанной записи в таблице *** " ".

Что не так, в чем проблема?

Comment: я думаю Вам в раздел SQL ;-), может стоит прислушаться к зову серд..тьфу к сообщению об ошибке, и подумать: что вы вставляете в ДБ и какие констрэйнты на таблице?

Comment: какая БД, что за код и пр.

Comment: База данных data.mdb, своего кода практически нет, только выставляю в элементах DataSource... Вставляю только таблицу(tdbgrid), навигатор, ADOTable, Datasource. Наверно это мало информации... А с чем это может быть связано? Что такое Primary Key? Нашел его где-то и пытался выставить в борланде, но борланд не дал, говорит что не поддерживается...

Comment: Primary Key - первичный коюч таблицы.
mdb - это аксес?
вот Ваш вопрос похоже (не цитирую, дабы не ставить копирайтов=)):
http://www.sql.ru/forum/1017048/nevozmozhno-dobavlenie-ili-izmenenie-zapisi-dlya-obespecheniya-celostnosti-dannyh-neobhodimo